# Hazelcast 5.1.3 performance issue due to Java Serialization

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We migrated Hazelcast from 3.x to 5.1.3.
It is observed that post migration, there is a big increase in the latency of iMap put operation.
This issue comes because of Java Serialization and it is suggested to use the [Hazelcast implementation of Serialization](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/serialization/implementing-dataserializable).
In order to implement DataSerializable interface, we need to override two methods i.e. readData & writeData in all the applicable classes.
As we have to implement this interface in thousands of classes, the efforts/time required would be very high and it will lead to delay in our project delivery.
Please let us know if there is any other way to implement this interface so that we can quickly migrate to the 5.x Hazelcast version.

Answer (score 1):

you were using Java serialization in 3.x as well I suppose.  You can try compact zero config serialization:

https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/serialization/compact-serialization#using-compact-serialization-with-zero-configuration

Though, note that using compact serialization with a explicit serializer will perform better. However, I think it will be good enough if you were using Java serialization. I don't think Java serialization is a fast serialization mechanism.

> This issue comes because of Java Serialization

Why do you think the issue is due to serialization? I think you can add more details about the issue. If you were using Java serialization in 3.x as well, I did not get why it got slower in 5.x.